# How to split a string file name using regular expression?

Tags: java, android, regex, split

I need to split the following string in one go in to an array. following is the string

"camera01_2012-04-13-10-14-12-625.jpg"

My code is `String[] fileNameParts = fi.getName().split("[_-.]");`

But it throws an exception saying "Exception: Syntax error U_REGEX_INVALID_RANGE near index 4:"

Comment: Want to parse  3 parts like this; camera01 , 2012-04-13-10-14-12, 625.jpg ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`-` within character class is used for representing a range

To treat `-` literally in character class it can be at the beginning or end

With `_-.` you are representing a range of `95`(decimal equivalent to ascii _) to `46`(decimal equivalent to ascii .) which is invalid.

Use this regex

```
[-_.]
```